# Weird red circle appears after, undoing applyed skin modifier

Tags: edit-mode

After playing with the skin modifier this weird circle happend.[image].What i did was basically i applyed a skin modifier at the curve shown then i undo and this appears O.o.

[image]

Comment: Could you give more details? Upload a blend?

Comment: @pycoder blend file added if my question is still unclear please don't hesitate to tell me ;)

Comment: This indicates the root of the skin modifier, but it should't be there without the modifier, most probably the way you did the undo created a bug. Try to save the file and reopen it.

Comment: @Denis i saved it and re-opened it but its still there :/ , also i have the .blend file available for download.

Comment: @xlxs add and remove the skin modifier, it should go away

Answer (score 2):

This marks the root of the *Skin* modifier. You can change the root vertex in the skin modifier tab by selecting your new root vertex and clicking *Mark Root*.